# how can i make todo highlight extension work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded the todo highlight extension. what should I write in json file for it to work? I copied the whole code from marketplace visual studio com but it doesn't work.
what exactly do you have written in this file? (I don't even care about the colors and stuff I just want the highlight to work.)

Comment: +i watched the tutorials and it doesnt work i just need the code that i know works

Comment: You can just install it through the extensions tab in VS code, you don't need to copy any code from a website. If you need information about how to install extensions in VS code, take a look at [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/extend).

Comment: thanks i already donwloaded it but i cannot use it. i doesn't do anything when i type the key words

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"todohighlight.isEnable": true,
"todohighlight.isCaseSensitive": true,
"todohighlight.keywords": [
    "DEBUG:",
    "REVIEW:",
    {
        "text": "NOTE:",
        "color": "#ff0000",
        "backgroundColor": "yellow",
        "overviewRulerColor": "grey"
    },
    {
        "text": "HACK:",
        "color": "#000",
        "isWholeLine": false,
    },
    {
        "text": "TODO:",
        "color": "red",
        "border": "1px solid red",
        "borderRadius": "2px", //NOTE: using borderRadius along with `border` or you will see nothing change
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,.2)",
        //other styling properties goes here ... 
    }
],
"todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "TODO:|FIXME:|\\(([^)]+)\\)", //highlight `TODO:`,`FIXME:` or content between parentheses
"todohighlight.defaultStyle": {
    "color": "red",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffab00",
    "overviewRulerColor": "#ffab00",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "border": "1px solid #eee",
    "borderRadius": "2px",
    "isWholeLine": true,
    //other styling properties goes here ... 
},
"todohighlight.include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.html",
    "**/*.php",
    "**/*.css",
    "**/*.scss"
],
"todohighlight.exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/bower_components/**",
    "**/dist/**",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.vscode/**",
    "**/.github/**",
    "**/_output/**",
    "**/*.min.*",
    "**/*.map",
    "**/.next/**"
],
"todohighlight.maxFilesForSearch": 5120,
"todohighlight.toggleURI": false
```

}